# Select first item on clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

I use `typeahead`(https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) on my textfield.

I have sat `autoSelect: true` when initializing `typeahead`

The problem is when my users write only some of the words, and not press'es enter or select a suggestion from the list, and just presses the submit-button, typeahead do not autoselect the first item.

How can I make typeahead select the first suggestion when clicking on a submit button?

///// I have made a quick fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/q6ESy/1 -> Try write 'a' and press enter, the alert will only alert 'a' and not 'alabama'

Comment: please provide ur code or fiddle

Comment: It is not really possible to provide a fiddle of the problem. It is not really a bug in typeahead or my code (I think). 
http://jsfiddle.net/q6ESy/1/ -> Try write 'a' and press enter, the alert will only alert 'a' and not 'alabama'

Answer (score 0):

I have done some edits in onsubmit code.. Actually on submit of the typehead.. suggestion list get closed.. I have set the first option to the query input onsubmit function...

hope it will work for you..

```
if($(".tt-suggestions")){
    var myVal = $(".tt-suggestion:first-child p").text();

    $query.typeahead('val', myVal);
    $query.typeahead('close');
}
```

Here is the working fiddle.. let me know you if you need any more edits...

http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/q6ESy/2/

Comment: It do still not work when you type 'a' and press on the button

Comment: it is working on press of enter.. let me check for button click too.